# Microsoft 365 mail signature setting using Angular

Tags: angular, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, office-js

I have been looking for an API to set mail signatures in Microsoft 365 using Angular. The client logs in using using Microsoft Authentication Library on an angular web application and he can set email signatures for users in the tenant. From what I have gotten from microsoft graph rest api they do not provide endpoints for setting up mail signature. Is there a better way I can accomplish this task using angular

Comment: Signatures are stored on the client and not on the server so the API has no way to access them. It follows that your Angular app would not either unless you interrogate the user's client somehow.

Comment: @MikePoole you can access an OWA signature via UserConfiguration in EWS that is if it's been setup. I stumbled across this response when trying to research doing the same via Graph due to the on coming retirement of EWS. Eventually signatures will be stored centrally but yet to be implemented by MS